# Flutter firestore write data with specific key

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I want to upload some data to Firestore but I can't figure out how to set specific key to data. I found this was discussed here before but with old Firebase database, now syntax is different.

```
Future<void> writeProfileData(Map<String, dynamic> profileData) async {
await _databaseReference
    .collection('profile')
    .add(profileData)
    .catchError((error) => print(error.toString()));
}
```

Now my data key is autogenerated and I want to have soething like .key(profileData['uid'])

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following syntax:

```
Future<void> writeProfileData(Map<String, dynamic> profileData) async {
  var ref = Firestore.instance.document('profile/profileData');
  ref.setData(profileData);
}
```